AddeventListener con mouseover y mouseout en arrreglos
Tengo elementos que muestro a través de un arreglo que se llena desde una base datos. Uno de los elementos es una imagen. Mi idea es que al pasar el ratón por la imagen esta desaparezca y se reproduzca un vídeo, cuyo enlace también está en la base de datos.
He conseguido acceder a la base de datos con JS y accedo a los enlaces de los vídeos sin problema. Abajo pongo el código que he pensado:


//Selecciono los elementos padre e hijo a través de las clases

    const divImagEnt = document.querySelectorAll('.divImagEnt');
    const imagenEntr = document.querySelectorAll('.imagenEnt');
    
    //Llamo para que se ejecute lo siguiente, en todas las imágenes de los arreglos, tras lo que he visto en otras preguntas y por internet
    
    for (var i = 0; i < divImagEnt.length; i++) {
            // console.log('hola');
            divImagEnt[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
                imagenEnt[i].style.visibility = "visible";
            });
        }
        
        for (var i = 0; i < divImagEnt.length; i++) {
            divImagEnt[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                imagenEnt[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
                
            });           
        }
        
        
<div class="divImagEnt">
            <picture class="imagenEnt">  
                <!-- Aquí iría la imagen -->
            </picture>

            <div class="persona__disponible--texto">
              <!-- Texto como pie de imagen que no quiero que se quite -->
            </div>
        </div>



Pero no consigo que la imagen se quite (y entonces la idea es añadir el video mientras el ratón esté encima y si no quitar el video y poner la imagen de nuevo y así sucesivamente con todos los elementos)
Me sale que el elemento no está definido al mover el ratón por encima y fuera:
Uncaught TypeError: i[e] is undefined
Mirando se refiere a
imagenEntrenador[i].style.visibility = "visible";
y
imagenEntrenador[i].style.visibility = "visible";
¿Por qué sale este error? Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para conseguir lo que he propuesto es bienvenida.
Gracias

¿En dónde está colocado el javascript? (¿en un script antes de cerrar el body?) ¿Está además dentro de un evento, como DOMContentLoaded?

Está en una función IIFE  que se ejecuta, diría yo, correctamente, ya que todo lo demás que tengo funciona, salvo lo que comento ahí. Pero también estoy en nivel aprendiz en programación, para ser honestos.

Porque tal vez el elemento al que hacés referencia aún no existe en el DOM, por eso vuelvo a preguntar: ¿está tu código dentro de un evento, como DOMContentLoaded?

DOMContentLoaded no lo utilizo, revisando todo mi código. Simplemente llamo a los del ratón al pasar por encima o salir del elemento. ¿Cómo sería tu idea entonces?

Respuesta relacionada (ver solo lo del DOMContentLoaded).

aqui tienes un ejemplo simple:


function playVideo(item) {
  const video = item.querySelector('.gallery-video');
  video.style.display = 'block';
  video.play();
}

function pauseVideo(item) {
  const video = item.querySelector('.gallery-video');
  video.pause();
  video.style.display = 'none';
}
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.gallery-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.gallery-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.gallery-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: none;
}
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-item" onmouseover="playVideo(this)" onmouseout="pauseVideo(this)">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Imagen 1">
    <video class="gallery-video" muted loop>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Tu navegador no soporta la etiqueta de video.
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item" onmouseover="playVideo(this)" onmouseout="pauseVideo(this)">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Imagen 2">
    <video class="gallery-video" muted loop>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Tu navegador no soporta la etiqueta de video.
    </video>
  </div>
    <div class="gallery-item" onmouseover="playVideo(this)" onmouseout="pauseVideo(this)">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Imagen 1">
    <video class="gallery-video" muted loop>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Tu navegador no soporta la etiqueta de video.
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item" onmouseover="playVideo(this)" onmouseout="pauseVideo(this)">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Imagen 2">
    <video class="gallery-video" muted loop>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Tu navegador no soporta la etiqueta de video.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>




Pues sí funciona, lo agregue a mi código y con esos mismos vídeos y funcionó. Intenté ahora hacerlo con vídeos de youtube. Vi que era con iframe en lugar de de la etiqueta video.
Pero si no me equivoco, el control de reproducir y pausar cambia, no? ¿Es posible hacer en este caso lo mismo?
Gracias
